# How to save checkbox selection mode based on user selection

Tags: php, html, jquery

I want the position of the checkbox to be saved when my form is submitted.

The problem with my code is that if the user enables or disables the checkbox; after submitting the form, the checkbox is marked and the user's choice is not taken into account.

My code:

```php
<?php
function tets_checkBox() {
  if (isset($_POST['submit-post'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['email-post'])) {
      echo '<p class="alert alert-success">' . __('The checkbox is checked.') . '</p>';
    } else {
      echo '<p class="alert alert-danger">' . __('The checkbox is not checked.') . '</p>';
    }
    echo '<p class="alert alert-success">' . __('The settings for your account have been updated') . '</p>';        
  }
}
?>
  
<form method="post" action=" ">             
  <aside class="account_news">
    <label class="account_mainBtn">
      <input type="checkbox" name="email-post" checked>
    </label>
    <h3>Select.</h3>
  </aside>          
  <input type="submit" name="submit-post" value="<?php _e('Update settings'); ?>">          
</form>
```

---

**Edit:**

I have placed this form on the user account page and the user selects the check box to send or not send email by the site.

I want when the user selects the checkbox mode; Save the checkbox mode for that user so that after logging out and re-entering the account, the checkbox mode is still maintained for that user.

Comment: I suggest to use localStorage...

Comment: Hi. Is there a way to do this with **PHP**? (save check box mode)

Comment: You can save it in a database.

Comment: Can you guide me for this? Or at least introduce a sample code or tutorial related to it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem or a jQuery problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$checked_attr = "checked='checked'";
$flag = 0;

if ( isset( $_POST['submit-post'] ) ) {
    $flag = 1;
}

if ( 1 === $flag ) {
    $checked_attr = ''; 
    if ( isset( $_POST['email-post'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['email-post'] ) ) {
        $checked_attr = "checked='checked'";
    }
} 

tets_checkBox();
?>
<form method="POST" action="" >
                    
            <aside class="account_news">

                 <label class="account_mainBtn">
                     <input type="checkbox" name="email-post" <?php echo $checked_attr; ?>  >
                  </label>

                 <h3>Select.</h3>
            </aside>
                        
    <input type="submit" name="submit-post" value="<?php echo( 'Update settings' ); ?>">
                        
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for writing the code. Your code correctly saves the state of the checkbox after submitting the form. But there are two other problems. First: In the first case, the checkbox is empty. Second: After leaving the page and re-entering the same page, the checkbox state will return to the default (empty).

Comment: I am using this code in the user account page and I want the mode selected by the user to remain forever until she changes it again.

Comment: @Benjamin I have updated the code to fix your mentioned issues
"Your code correctly saves the state of the checkbox after submitting the form. But there are two other problems. First: In the first case, the checkbox is empty. Second: After leaving the page and re-entering the same page, the checkbox state will return to the default (empty)."

Comment: @Benjamin
To fix this issue "I am using this code in the user account page and I want the mode selected by the user to remain forever until she changes it again"


Kindly provide the code to update the user data in DB and fetch the data from DB meta so that I can fix it for you. But before that I want you take an attempt to try it by your own.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply handle by checking **isset** or **empty** function when a user check the checkbox you will get the **email-post** field in action else the field will undefined

```
if(!empty($_POST['email-post'])){
 echo '<p class="alert alert-success">' . __( 'The checkbox is checked.' ) . '</p>';
}else{
 echo '<p class="alert alert-danger">' . __( 'The checkbox is not checked.' ) . '</p>';
}
```

the **!empty** function check both is the variable exists and the variable is not empty. Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I tried your code and not only did it not solve my problem but it also created a new problem. After running your code, error messages will appear without clicking the (**update settings**) button and will remain even after refreshing the page.

Comment: add this code in your existing code don't copy paste it. use the code  `if (isset($_POST['submit-post'])) {` inside this block